# Nested query in SQL Server to get array of JSON and object of JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
{
    "Output": { "ENTITYDEFINITION": [ { "screenconfig": 1,
                                        "entitytype": 2,
                                        "entitydefname": "Customer",
                                        "entitydefid": 1
                                      }]
              }
}
```

I need this output but I'm not able to get it.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    entitydef_id [ENTITYDEFINITION.entitydefid],
    entity_name [ENTITYDEFINITION.entitydefname],
    entitytype [ENTITYDEFINITION.entitytype],
    screenjson [ENTITYDEFINITION.screenconfig]
FROM 
    mytable A  
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Output'), include_null_values
```

Comment: did you try this https://sqlify.io/convert/json/to/sql

Comment: @Hiten004  -- not helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get your result using only JSON functions, next approach may help:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    entitydef_id int,
    entity_name varchar(10),
    entitytype int,
    screenjson int
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (entitydef_id, entity_name, entitytype, screenjson)
VALUES
   (1, 'Customer', 5, 2),
   (2, 'Customer', 15, 12)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (    
   SELECT TOP 1 *
   FROM #Data
   FOR JSON AUTO
) j([Output.ENTITYDEFINITION])
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Output:

```
{"Output":{"ENTITYDEFINITION":[{"entitydef_id":1,"entity_name":"Customer","entitytype":5,"screenjson":2}]}}
```